# How get get Items with same parent ID - to populate a dropdownlistfor in EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, foreign-keys, parent-child, html.dropdownlistfor

I have parent-child (1 to Many) table, AKA *Foreign Key* table.

`Dad Table`   *-> many children in* `Children Tables`

`Id, DadName`    ->   `Id, DadId, ChildName`

I have one value of in the child table i.e. `I know Sarah/ iD 27`, i.e. I know one child and would like to find out - who the other children are in her family under her dad. How can I do this in EF?

**How can I get the reset of the adjacent siblings, in a dropdownlistfor with the same parentID (dadId) given a childId**?

```
 FamilyRow.FamilyList = db.Children
     .Where(x => x.Dad (Dad.FirstOrDefault(y => y.ID == x.Child.Id));  
     .Select(x => new SelectListItem()
            {                    
                Value = x.Id.ToString(),  // is this needed?? 
                Text = x.ChildName                   
            }).SortByDescending..;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Get the parent Id for given child

```
Int32 parentId = db.Children.Where(x=>x.ChildId == GivenChildId).FirstOrDefault().ParentID;
```

If Parent Id is not null then get all the children which have this parent Id

```
if(parentId != null)
{
    List<Children> lstChildren = db.Children.Where(x=>x.ParentID == parentId).ToList();
}
```

Comment: thanks, what if I had a cache list of the parents `var parentsCached = db.Parents.Where(x = x.shcoolId = 10)` can I use that to filter as well rather than hitting the db everytime